# Reference to .NET Framework 4.7.2 error during build but not in solution

Tags: c#, .net, docker

I'm getting an error during my build step (via a GitHub action, attempting a Docker script) that says:

> /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/8.0.100/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1241,5): error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks [/src/rardk.web.UI/rardk.web.UI.esproj]

This version isn't referenced in my application as far as I can tell, as it's a .NET 8.0 application.

It should be running in [this step](https://github.com/rarDevelopment/rardk-web-dotnet/blob/908dab1e33b3689216b3a37684e9708ef4505214/.github/workflows/docker-publish.yml#L44) in the GitHub Action, and also [here's a link to the repo itself](https://github.com/rarDevelopment/rardk-web-dotnet/tree/dev) (dev branch) to see if I'm missing anything. The relevance of the GitHub Action is that it's an attempt to get this running in a Docker container, but the Docker container shouldn't need any .NET Framework references I wouldn't think.

Comment: Your UI project is the culprit. You have a reference to it in your API project. I haven't encountered esproj files before. Maybe they're only supported on Windows? If you remove the reference, your project builds OK.

Comment: Yeah I'm thinking I'll split the frontend out of this application anyway, so this worked. Thank you!